# Store sql results in session? Is this ok?

Tags: mysql, session, caching, store

I'm working on a website where I use sessions to log in my users AND to store their search results (up to 480 row, 18 columns - EDIT: about 35KB of data after gzcompress)

this is what i do:

```
$_SESSION['results_cache']= gzcompress(serialize($results),2);
```

And when i need to read it of course:

```
$results = unserialize(gzuncompress($_SESSION['results_cache']));
```

I need to do this because my results are never the same, they are ordered by date, and they can be updated at a high frequency.
So to go through the different pages without messing the results, i need to save the results.

I'm not sure my way is ok, and i'm not sure how it will work with, let's say, 100 000 users(i'm optimistic :).

If anyone could give me their opinion.

Comment: 480 rows doesn't say much. just how BIG will the serialized data be? you don't want to be stuffing (say() 10 gigs of blob data in the session. with 100,000 users, that'd be just ever so slightly heavy on storage space requirements...

Comment: I guess it will be more like 3.5GB of data for the whole 100 000 users.. Well then what would be a good solution if it's going to be too heavy? I can't think of anything else. In any case, it will take some disk space.

Comment: 35kb compressed isn't much, disk-wise, but it's still a fairly heavy hit at the startup of the script, which'd be done EVERY time a user hits a page that's session-enabled. of course, there aren't much better alternatives. the other major one would be simply store the query parameters and re-run the query each time, which just shifts the load from files-on-disk to queries-hitting-other-files-on-disk.

Comment: I'm doing this too, I'm storing the parameters of the query into a cookie.
Actually when you reach the search page, if parameters have been stored, I use them to refresh the search results and show them directly(and save new results into session). While the search results stored in the session are used to load more results(with jquery) for the search made at the time it was made. As i said, i can only do it this way since the results can change at any time. If i don't do it this way, I'll end up showing duplicate results on the different pages, and it won't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what i did.

Since I have a function that cans retrieve a product by ID, I change my search results to only return necessary columns, "id" and 2 more, which are created on the go in the request, and needed to order the results.

Meaning I have now 480 rows of 3 columns which contains only int (id => int(10), column2 => int(3), column3 => int(1))

Id is of course, an index, so it shouldn't take much database ressource to retrieve a row, i only show 12 rows per page.

Does it sound better doing things this way?

I now make 12 more short request per page, but i saved like 30kb of data per member.